# How to find the number of math books from a box of six books and some math books, if probability of choosing a novel is 3/5

Tags: probability

A box contains six novels and some math books. If we randomly choose a book from the box the probability of choosing a novel is $3/5$, find the number of math books in the box.

Comment: Hint: Let $m$ be the number of math books and $n$ the number of novels.  The probability of choosing a math book is $\frac{m}{m+n}$ and the probability of choosing a novel is $\frac{n}{m+n}$ (*assuming there are only math books and novels in the box and each book is equally likely to have been selected*).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let the number of math books be $m$. Then the total number of books in the box is $6+m$, and the probability of choosing a novel is $\frac{6}{6+m}$. Then the equation
$$\frac{6}{6+m}=\frac{3}{5}$$
You should be able to use this to solve for the number of math books.

Comment: I see now I had the equation set up wrong, i had 6+x/6, I was stuck and couldn't see the mistake, now i feel like i shouldn't have asked this question at all, but thanks

Comment: Don't worry about it!

Answer (score 1):

$x$ is the total number of books and there are $6$ novels.
$$\frac{6}{x}=\frac{3}{5}$$
$$x=10$$ In total 10 books, 6 of which are novels. There are $10-6=4$ math books